# Crash with EXC_BAD_ACCESS in Xcode - debugging

Tags: xcode, cocoa, lldb, appkit, nsautoreleasepool

I occasionally run into a crash with my Mac app, where the debugger stops and catches an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error from main.m. The stack trace looks like as follows:

```
* thread #1: tid = 0x406ad1, 0x00007fff8be600d7 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_msgSend + 23, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x600036e8de50)
frame #0: 0x00007fff8be600d7 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_msgSend + 23
frame #1: 0x00007fff96edb93b AppKit`_NSPopoverCloseAndAnimate + 1102
frame #2: 0x00007fff9754cfed AppKit`-[NSPopover _geometryInWindowDidChangeForView:] + 166
frame #3: 0x00007fff8bb15cdc CoreFoundation`__CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 12
frame #4: 0x00007fff8ba07244 CoreFoundation`_CFXNotificationPost + 3140
frame #5: 0x00007fff8ffa6c31 Foundation`-[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 66
frame #6: 0x00007fff96ca31c1 AppKit`-[NSView _invalidateFocus] + 421
frame #7: 0x00007fff96ca3c32 AppKit`-[NSView removeFromSuperview] + 469
frame #8: 0x00007fff96ea569a AppKit`-[NSWindow dealloc] + 1233
frame #9: 0x00007fff96ca9857 AppKit`-[NSWindow release] + 193
frame #10: 0x00007fff8ba0f9c0 CoreFoundation`CFRelease + 304
frame #11: 0x00007fff8ba23fad CoreFoundation`-[__NSArrayM dealloc] + 205
frame #12: 0x00007fff8be8089c libobjc.A.dylib`objc_object::sidetable_release(bool) + 236
frame #13: 0x00007fff8be66e8f libobjc.A.dylib`(anonymous namespace)::AutoreleasePoolPage::pop(void*) + 575
frame #14: 0x00007fff8ba31302 CoreFoundation`_CFAutoreleasePoolPop + 50
frame #15: 0x00007fff8ffbfedf Foundation`-[NSAutoreleasePool drain] + 153
frame #16: 0x00007fff96c7e661 AppKit`-[NSApplication run] + 800
frame #17: 0x00007fff96c69a14 AppKit`NSApplicationMain + 1832
frame #18: 0x0000000100003ec2 Contacts Journal Beta`main(argc=3, argv=0x00007fff5fbff670) + 34 at main.m:13
frame #19: 0x00007fff977c35c9 libdyld.dylib`start + 1
```

I've tried debugging this with NSZombieEnabled and with the Zombies instrument, and they haven't been helpful. But the debugger does stop at this breakpoint (on the rare occasions I run into this crash), so I'm wondering if there is anything I can do with the debugger to get more information as to which object is causing this crash and why.

Would love some lldb tips. Also, is there any way to force the "NSAutoreleasePool drain" that seems to be part of the stack trace? It seems to me that this is the initial cause of the problem, so any fix would have to trigger an autorelease drain (use ARC in my app).

Comment: Did you try to enable Guard Malloc debug option?

Comment: Post-ARC, you can force a pool drain with `@autoreleasepool{}` enclosures.